# How to mock HTTP request. I am using the NPM request package. Nock doesn't seem to work

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, npm, mocha.js, nock

I am trying to use Nock. It is matching the URL as per my mock definition.

Though the problem is that my actual request is failing. And I am not being able to test for my response that I am setting up using Nock.

My nock definition looks like so:

```js
nock(process.env.BASE_URL)
.post("/v1.0/api/item", JSON.stringify({"key": "S123"}))
.reply(200, "K123")
.log((data) => console.log(data));
```

```js
request.post({
  headers: headers,
  url: process.env.BASE_URL + '/' + url,
  body: JSON.stringify(body)
}, function (error, response) {
  if ( error ) {
     ...
  }
  
}
```

It's entering the error block. Is this expected?

Comment: Posting the code you're using would help us help you.

Comment: What does the error say? Have you looked at the message? Without that it's going to be difficult to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to my issue. I realised that I have to provide the expected response json to .reply() to nock.